# ng2-datetime : TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

Tags: angular

I install ng2-datetime#v1.1.4 (not RC5 version) and try to add datetime component to my test application.  I run into the following error.  Please help if you know what it is.  Thanks.

```
browser_adapter.js:84 TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
    at NKDatetime.init (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:27185:59)
    at NKDatetime.ngAfterViewInit (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:27115:15)
    at DebugAppView._View_Crud0.detectChangesInternal (Crud.template.js:1428:62)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:60629:15)
    at DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:60734:45)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:60655:20)
    at DebugAppView._View_Crud_Host0.detectChangesInternal (Crud.template.js:40:8)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:60629:15)
    at DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:60734:45)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectContentChildrenChanges (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:60647:20)
    at DebugAppView._View_ServicesMain0.detectChangesInternal (ServicesMain.template.js:376:8)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:60629:15)
    at DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:60734:45)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:60655:20)
    at DebugAppView._View_ServicesMain_Host0.detectChangesInternal (ServicesMain.template.js:37:8)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:60629:15)
    at DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:60734:45)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectContentChildrenChanges (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:60647:20)
    at DebugAppView._View_App0.detectChangesInternal (App.template.js:88:8)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:60629:15)
    at DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:60734:45)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:60655:20)
    at DebugAppView._View_App_Host0.detectChangesInternal (App.template.js:40:8)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:60629:15)
    at DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:60734:45)
    at ViewRef_.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:47800:66)
    at http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:34125:85
```

Comment: I've the same problem... all bundles are loaded... also i tried installing typings definition for bootstrap-datetimepicker with no results.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue with webpack,
I have following entries for the webpack

```
config.entry = {
     webapp:['./client/main.js'], //application generated code will be here 
     polyfills:['./client/polyfills.browser.js'], //pollyfills will be here
     vendor:['./client/vendor.browser.js'] //external vendor files will be here.
};
```

My jQuery is been added to vendor.browser.ts file. And following code

```
import { NKDatetime } from 'ng2-datetime/ng2-datetime';  
@Component({   
    ...    
    directives: [NKDatetime],  
})
```

was in app.module.ts file. So It's not able to fetch the jQuery there.

So I have made following change.

Set the following code

```
import { NKDatetime } from 'ng2-datetime/ng2-datetime';
export {NKDatetimeModule} //export the ng2 module from the vendor.ts file.
```

In vendor.ts file.

and

```
//import the exported ng2-datetime module here.
import { NKDatetimeModule } from '../../vendor.browser'; 
@Component({
    ...
    directives: [NKDatetime],
})
```

In my app.module.ts file.

And It works...

Comment: I've same issue but I'm using angular-webpack2-starter bootstrap branch, without vendor.ts file...how can fix the issue?  https://github.com/qdouble/angular-webpack2-starter/tree/bootstrap v

Answer (score 0):

You did not include the jquery bootstrap-datepicker plugin as instructed in the readme of ng2-datetime.

https://github.com/nkalinov/ng2-datetime#dependencies

`npm install --save bootstrap-datepicker`

> or use the bundled version
>   from src/vendor/bootstrap-datepicker

It's enough to put the

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>`

and it should work.

Comment: You're right so I make sure all dependencies are done.  All files are loaded okay not 404 like before.  However, I still get the same error.  I debug and get exception at line 140 in init() of ng2-datetime.ts ==>    private init(): void {
        if (!this.datepicker && this.datepickerOptions !== false) {
            this.datepicker = (<any>$('#' + this.idDatePicker)).datepicker(this.datepickerOptions);

Comment: I step inside jQuery and it shows context is undefined at line 94 ==> return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context );   I'm using jQuery version 3.0.0

Comment: Check the demo under https://nkalinov.github.io/ng2-datetime/ for usage examples. Also check your Angular  2 version number if it is supported by your version of ng2-datetime.

Comment: Thanks I'll do that.  The component is added to my page but when I click on it I get the exception.  Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment on Alexander Ciesielski's answer, but I don't have enough reputation for that.  Sorry.

I had ng2-datetime installed in my app and 'working' (the datepicker was working, the timepicker only sometimes).

Then I switched from using gulp to angular-cli beta 15.  After lots breakage fixing (a bit like putting Humpty Dumpty back together!), I got it working again except for the error in the original question.

"bootstrap-datepicker" had been installed as in Alexander's answer:

```
npm install --save bootstrap-datepicker
```

I checked and it is included in the produced js bundle, but I still get the error.

I added the explicit script tag inclusion as in Alexander's answer:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Now it works.  (Well datepicker works. Timepicker doesn't work, but it doesn't give an error either.  Explicitly including timepicker.js doesn't help here.)

Hope this helps.

Versions of packages in node_modules:

```
ng2-datetime: 1.2.0
bootstrap-datepicker: 1.6.4
bootstrap-timepicker: 0.5.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to vendor.ts

```
import 'bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css';
import 'bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js';
import 'bootstrap-timepicker/css/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css';
import 'bootstrap-timepicker/js/bootstrap-timepicker.js';
```